# Is there a way to keep the sidebar along with right side content and still have nested routes in React Router v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to have a sidebar with some cards on the right. When I click on a card, I want to navigate to a component named `Note` but still have the sidebar in left.

I followed this https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial but they don't have content on right so it works. I tried finding it everywhere but couldn't.

Here's my router so far (App has sidebar and cards):

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "notes/:id",
        element: <Note />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Comment: Looking at https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#nested-routes does your `App` render an `<Outlet>` component?

Comment: No, App is seperate. I'm using App as Root

Comment: Without `<Outlet>` in the `App` component, the child root will not render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React Router v6, you can achieve a layout with a fixed sidebar and dynamic content as below.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import Cards from './Cards';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <Sidebar />
      <Cards />
      <div style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: '250px' }}>
        {/* Outlet renders the matched child route component */}
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In this example, **Sideba**r and **Cards** components are rendered on the left, and the **Outlet** component renders the matched child route component on the right. The **flex: 1** style on the right container ensures that it takes up the remaining space, pushing the content to the right side.
Now, your router configuration might look like this:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <div>Home Page</div>,
      },
      {
        path: 'notes/:id',
        element: <Note />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Comment: it just changes the url but doesn't change the content. doesn't replace cards with new content, instead add that content in same screen

Comment: do you want the sidebar to remain constant, but the content on the right should change from displaying cards to displaying the Note component when a card is clicked. like this ?

Comment: Yes exactly! And your provided solution worked. So thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `<Outlet/>` component in your `<App/>` component via `import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom"`.